# Regex - First character stripped

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex with the following requirements:

From a block of text, get the inner text of the `url(...)`.
If the inner text starts with `data`, it should be ignored.

The regex below seems to work the only problem is it is removing the first letter of in results.

Expected result:

```
../public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
https://public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
../public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
../public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular
```

Actual result (missing first character):

```
./public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
ttps://public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
./public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
./public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular
```

Regex

```
(?s)url\([^data:](.*?)\);?
```

Text

```
src: url(../public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
src: url(https://public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
src: url(../public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(data:application/font-woff;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICIuL2Rpc3QvYXNzZXRzL2ZvbnRzL2dseXBoaWNvbnMtaGFsZmxpbmdzLXJlZ3VsYXIud29mZjIiOw==) format('woff2'),url(data:application/font-woff;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICIuL2Rpc3QvYXNzZXRzL2ZvbnRzL2dseXBoaWNvbnMtaGFsZmxpbmdzLXJlZ3VsYXIud29mZiI7) format('woff'),url(../public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'),url(../public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format('svg');
}
```

How do I get that first character selected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that acc. to your requirements, given your sample input, there are 5 matches, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the negated character class with a negative lookahead:

```
url\((?!data)(.*?)\)
      ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yPZQj9/1)

**Details**:

- `url\(` - a literal string `url(`
- `(?!data)`  - the next for chars should not be a `data` substring
- `(.*?)` - capturing group 1 matching any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first
- `\)` -  `)` symbol.